# Get latest from pivot result in Laravel eloquent style

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I have 2 tables : tournament and user

In the tournament model, I have a belongsToMany relationship

```
    public function competitors()
{

    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')
        ->withPivot('tournament_id', 'confirmed')
        ->withTimestamps();
}
```

Now, I would like to get the latest 5 result from the results of competitors()

It seems easy, but I don't know how to do it following eloquent style.

like for instance :

```
$latest = $tournament->competitors()->latest(5);
```

Thing is competitors() result is not a basic model, it is a join, so I can't write a function in a model...

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily order by pivot table's columns by prefixing pivot table's column with **pivot_**, e.g.:

```
$latest = $tournament->competitors()->orderBy('pivot_created_at', 'desc')->get();
```

Comment: How do you apply take()? This is the same "order by" like you would have for any other column, it can't break the query if applied correctly

Comment: I apply it like that: $latest = $tournament->competitors()->orderBy('pivot_created_at', 'desc')->take(5);

Comment: call to take() just applies the limit constraint, you still need to call get() to fetch the data